# @GetMapping with array parameters by application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have developed this **@GetMapping** RestController and all works fine

```
@GetMapping(path = {"foo", "bar"})
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}
```

now I want externalize the values inside the path array using my **application.yml** file,so I writed

```
url:
  - foo
  - bar
```

and I modified my code in order to use it, but it doesn't work in this two different ways

```
@GetMapping(path = "${url}")
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}

@GetMapping(path = {"${url}"})
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}
```

I don't understand if the application properties are not correctly formatted or I need to use the SpEL (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html.

I also want that the code is dynamic according to the application.yml properties, so if the *url* values increase or decrease the code must still work.

I'm using **Springboot** 1.5.13

Comment: You should try @ConfigurationProperties annotation to fetch yml configuration data.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 and after that? How I can use the fetched properties and inject it in the **@GetMapping** annotation? You cannot inject variable in the annotation, only constant

Answer (score 4):

You can't bind `YAML` list to array or list here. For more information see: [@Value and @ConfigurationProperties behave differently when binding to arrays](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/501)

However, you can achieve this by specifying regular expression in yml file like:

```
url: '{var:foo|bar}'
```

And then you can use it directly in your controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "${url}")
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work because you have only defined a **PathVariable** that is called _foo|bar_ so the endpoint is matched by all the call like (http://localhost/anytypeofrequest)

Comment: @FedericoGatti Thanks, missed it. Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, in this way is possible to define a PathVaribale only for one of the two urls? Something like `url: '{var:foo/{foobar}|bar}'`

Comment: @FedericoGatti `var` is name of your `@PathVariable`. I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use in your controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "${url[0]}")
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}

@GetMapping(path = {"${url[1]}"})
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}
```

Or you can do in this way:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"${url[0]}","${url[1]}"})
public ResponseEntity<String> foobar() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("foobar");
}
```

I think this is helpful

Comment: Thank you, your second solutions work fine with a specific number of url in the properties,  I'm searching for a dynamic solution for any number of values inside the array